# Parabolic inductions for p-adic reductive groups

Tags: reference-request, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups

So I wish to ask for articles/comments surveying conjectures and theorems about parabolic induction for p-adic (non-archimedean case) reductive groups, and how local Langlands behaves under such. That is:

1. For a quasi-split group G, what we know about the sub-representations of principle series.
2. Same setting, but what we know about the (enhanced) Langlands parameters they correspond to, both conjectures and theorems.
3. Same questions in 1 & 2, but for parabolic induction of supercuspidal representations from Levi assumed local Langlands for that Levi is understood.

The only things I know is the articles of Bernstein-Zelevinsky that addresses part of 1 and somewhat 2 for GL_n, as well as recent work of Aubert-Moussaoui-Solleveld (and extensions of some of them with others) about a nice conjectural framework of 3.

Any comment is greatly appreciated! I am also under the impression that the above questions are largely known for classical groups given the local Langlands established by Arthur and many others, but love to know a reference good for quick reading. If more is known in the local function field case, it will be fantastic to learn too. Thank you very much!!!